# Cocoa UI on terminal app

Tags: c, cocoa, terminal, osx-yosemite

I've been tasked to build a Cocoa interface for a C terminal application.

There are no requirments other than the GUI.

My question is:
Would it be best and/or fastest to make the terminal calls or get source code  (which I do have authorization to use) and call the functions directly from Cocoa?

Please state pros and cons for educational purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best (faster, easier) to call the functions directly from Cocoa.

Of course you realise that Cocoa apps must be Sandboxed if they are going on the Mac App Store and Sandboxing can make many, previously trivial, operations much more complicated?

Comment: Yeah, I talked to the client about this, they don't want it on the Mac App Store, it's for internal use only.